# Will a standard wifi enabled light switch between an indirect water heater and the furnace stop the heat call?

Tags: thermostat, water-heater, smart-switch

We have a Honeywell thermostat on an indirect water heater that ties to one of the zones on a furnace in a vacation home.  I'd like to be able to stop the call to heat the water if the house will be unoccupied for an extended period of time via a Wifi connection of some sort.  After some research it appears putting a standard Wifi enabled light switch on the line in between the water heater and the furnace switch box would do the trick.  Does that seam right, or are there better solutions?  I can't seem to find a smart thermostat that will work on an indirect water heater.

We keep the temperature in the house at around 56F when it's unoccupied during the winter, so I'm not concerned about the pipes freezing.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe but I've noted that some of these switches don't work well with unexpected loads.  They are designed to turn lights on or off, not thermostats.  You may find that you need to put a light on the circuit too so that the switch thinks it's turning something "real" on and off.

Comment: Also be sure you don't get a switch with an integrated dimmer function.  I believe that would cause severe problems and possibly damage to your thermostat.

Comment: An auquastat is what is used to set the temp limits on an indirect water heater.  I did  find a smart controller but i am not sure it works with indirect WH. -  https://aquanta.io/  - More research may yield other options.  Would you not want to maintain a minimum temp in your WH instead of no temp control at all?

Comment: Thanks jwh20 - I will take a look to make sure any type of switch I pick up will work with the load the line gives off.

Comment: And thanks too Alaska Man 1 - the aquanta does not work with boiler fed WHs (which I'm assuming means indirect).  I've been searching for a while and even asked Bradford White, but haven't heard back from them yet.  I'll keep doing my research and post my solution once I find it.